# Django models queries

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have 3 tables person(id, email,password,type), user_location(id,location,u_id) and reviews(id,review,from_id,to_id). The user_location(u_id) is the foreignkey to person(id). The review(from_id,to_id) is also foreignkey to person(id). So how can i filter out a person with type 'a' and location 'b' and the reviews he got with the reviewers name?

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pwd = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class User_locations(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    u_id = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your model file please?

Comment: @yvesonline my models.py file. i haven't created a review class yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I really understand what you're trying to do but this should point you in the right direction. Don't forget to refer to the doc for [Many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) and [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). It says there:

> To refer to a “reverse” relationship, use the lowercase name of the model.

And then use the normal `__` to access attributes.

```
a_and_b = Person.objects.filter(type='a', user_locations__location='b')
reviewers = Person.objects.filter(to_id__in=a_and_b)
```

The first query selects all users with `type` `a` and `location` `b`. The second query filters on those results. This is all untested so you might need to tweak a little. Bottom line: follow the relationships. As a side note, you might want to read up on Django model naming conventions.